# Best way to store field names in Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-models, rdbms

How to store field names which user can see.
What is the best/correct way to save rights/access to fields in table.

I want store in `UserModel` which fields allowed to this user, from `DataModel`

E.G: user is allowed to see name, commision and id, another user is allowed to see name, seller, price and custom_data_field7

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [django permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) system, or create something simpler, that will decide what fields should be shown based on user type. Depending on where would you like it to show (is it in template or REST API), I could come up with some ideas.

Comment: I need specify fields for each separate user. Not group but user.